# How to add emoji to menu in telegram bot python?

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm new in python and telegram bot developing, I'm trying to add emoji to bottom menu of the  telegram bot, but I don't know how. Buttons in chat have already emoji, but bottom bot menu haven't. Thank you.

Example of code:

```py
menu1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup([
    [InlineKeyboardButton(text=' Інформація', callback_data='info')],
    [InlineKeyboardButton(text=' Заборгованість', callback_data='arrears')],
    [InlineKeyboardButton(text=' Кабінет', callback_data='cabinet')],
    [InlineKeyboardButton(text=' Веб-сайт', url='')]])
```

Example of menu, that I've done:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add emoji in the same place where you add text

```
telegram.KeyboardButton(text="Hello ")
```

Comment: I'm edited post and added example of code, I need to add  emoji to bottom menu.

Comment: @Lemair which library are you using?

Comment: I'm use telebot.

Answer (score 1):

You can write down `user_keyboard_markup()` function and use it to display with each message you send. You can generate different functions to display different content depending on what users choose. You need just add `reply_markup=...` to your message.

*my_markups_folder/markups.py:*

```
def user_keyboard_markup():
    user_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
    button_site = KeyboardButton(text="Web site ")
    
    user_markup.row('/start', '/help', '/stop')
    user_markup.row('', '', '')
    user_markup.add(button_site)
    return user_markup

def my_other_keyboard_markup():
    return None
```

*main.py:*

```
...
from my_markups_folder.markups import user_keyboard_markup

...

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text(message):
    if message.text == "show me keyboard markup":
        
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                         text=f"""
        *Motpheus:*
        Welcome back, Neo!
        """, parse_mode='markdown', reply_markup=user_keyboard_markup())
```

and you will see something like this:

...

[image]